# Node.Js MongoParseError URI malformed, cannot be parsed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dotenv

When I run it on my local computer I don't get any problem, I encounter this error when I deploy it to Heroku. I don't fully understand the reason.

```
MongoParseError URI malformed, cannot be parsed
```

I just get this on Heroku. Also, my file on the server.js side is as follows.

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });
const app = require("./app");



const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  "<PASSWORD>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

console.log(DB);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MONGO_DB_USER,
      password: process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD,
    },
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB connection successful!"));
```

> "mongoose": "^5.13.14",   "mongoose-intl": "^3.3.0",   "dotenv":
> "^16.0.3",

My .env file has MongoDB URLs and passwords. That's why I don't share. Works great locally too. but there are problems in deployment.

Comment: Have you checked your console? What's the output for `console.log(DB);`?

Comment: yes I checked. I am getting the mongodb url.

Comment: Then it should work. because if `mongoose .connect` gets undefined it throws an error like you just got.

Comment: It works on my local computer, it doesn't work when I deploy it on heroku or elsewhere. and it was also working on heroku before. now, not working on heroku.

Comment: My local computer is also connected to atlas mongodb,

Comment: `process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD` vs `process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD` are those really two different values. And are both of them defined in your `.env` file? And did you really check in your *heroku*  logfile (not local), that `console.log(DB)` prints the correct value? Obviously there is something going wrong with your environment variables. Either it can't read the `.env` file at all, or some value is missing or wrong.

Comment: Seemingly `process.env.DATABASE` has some value `!== undefined` (otherwise the `.replace` would throw an exception) thus it *can*  read the `.env` file. So either the url in that variable is already malformed, or `DATABASE_PASSWORD` contains an invalid value. Can you share an *anonymized* version of your `.env` file. Ie replace passwords, usernames, hostname, dbname ... with dummy placeholders? Also can you share an *anonymized* output of `console.log(DB)`?

Comment: Our password doesn't contain any special characters. Only lower case and upper case letters and numbers. 
 
console.log(DB) => mongodb+srv://berner:mypassword@cluster0.cb1wz1k.mongodb.net/test

Comment: I agree with the parts you said. but it works in my local. If process.env was wrong, it wouldn't work on the atlas side in my local either. my locale and heroku see the same database. Could it be any network error or a bug in heroku's own systems?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it was caused by the fact that on heroku the node version was updated to 19.0.0.

*To find out which version of node is being used on heroku, run **heroku run 'node -e "console.log(process.versions)"'***

The error is caused by mongoose version, maybe you are using an old one.

To solve this, try to update to mongoose 6.7.2 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure your environment variables are same, it may be related to ip.
Try adding 0.0.0.0/0 IP address in Atlas Network Access. If you already have this IP, then delete and add it again. After that restart all dynos in Heroku. (inside dropdown menu at top right)

Comment: I did all of them but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

check your server dotenv value.

In a cloud environment the .env file may be different.

can you check local process.env and Heroku's process.env?

Comment: I'm constantly checking the config on heroku. whatever I change. i am getting the same error. and my local and heroku are looking at the same atlas. different tables. Could it be a problem with the versions?

Comment: Same here, it was working a few hours ago. I didn't change any config related to db, it looks like is something internal in heroku but I wasn't able to get any info about it.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with heroku

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error in your mongoDB URI
For now i don't know what your URI is which is .env file but i can suggest you a few things

1- Firstly you need to replace the first two lines of your code with this one

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

2- In your .env file you need to create a variable named

`MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://[username:password@]host[/[database][?options]]`

whatever your password and username is just fill in that here in URI

Finally you need to change the connection string and your file should look like this

```
require('dotenv').config();
const app = require("./app");

mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection Successfull");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Connection Unsuccessfull");
      });
```

Comment: I tried with plain string but i get the same error. I think, it has nothing to do with env variables