# Why I get this error "MongoParseError URI malformed, cannot be parsed"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });
const app = require('./app');

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

console.log(DB);
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

This is my code where I want to connect MongoDB server.

```
NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3000
DATABASE=mongodb+srv://muhosman:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.0kuwazr.mongodb.net/natours?retryWrites=true&w=majority
DATABASE_LOCAL=mongodb://localhost:27017/natours
DATABASE_PASSWORD=xxx

JWT_SECRET=my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret
JWT_EXPIRES_IN=90d
JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN=90

EMAIL_USERNAME=xxx
EMAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
EMAIL_PORT=25
```

This is my '.env' file.

I am using vs code. When I want to connect my mongoDB I am getting this error. I searched this error but the other posts doesn't help me . Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `replace` function looks wrong (read function documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace))

```
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  /(<PASSWORD>)/,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);
```

instead of

```
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);
```

Comment: ```const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace( '<PASSWORD>', process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD ); console.log(DB); 
```
I used console.log() for printing the DB and it gave to me this 

[nodemon] restarting due to changes... [nodemon] starting node server.js mongodb+srv://muhosman:ogTxPq6CB0qN8Vxq@cluster0.0kuwazr.mongodb.net/natours?retryWrites=true&w=majority App running on port 3000... UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down... MongoParseError URI malformed, cannot be parsed [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: if console.log(DB) prints the expected connection URL it must be something else. What is your mongoose driver version?

Comment: Those are my dependencies  ```"dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-mongo-sanitize": "^1.3.2",
        "express-rate-limit": "^3.5.0",
        "helmet": "^3.16.0",
        "hpp": "^0.2.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.13.15",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
        "slugify": "^1.3.4",
        "validator": "^10.11.0",
        "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
      }``` node js version is "19.1.0"

Comment: Is it working on your local machine or only when deploying to the production environment? (see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74456806/node-js-mongoparseerror-uri-malformed-cannot-be-parsed)